# Explicit properties of UserControl are ignored inside Generic.xaml

Tags: wpf

I have simple UserControl with default Width and Height specified inside in UserControl1.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication7.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Width="100" Height="100"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <Border Background="Blue"/>
</UserControl>
```

Then I put this UserControl inside custom control CustomControl1 and override Width and Height values in Generic.xaml :

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
                <local:UserControl1 Width="5" Height="5" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

For some reason when I instantiate my CustomControl1, I see that specified values of Width and Height are ignored.

[image: Screenshot]

Now, I have found a workaround for this problem.

But I want to understand why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Remove fixed width and height from your custom control.

```
   <UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication7.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

        <Border Background="Blue"/>
    </UserControl>
```

Should work when setting width and height in your main view.

Comment: That's basically how I overcome this problem. But the question is why Width and Height inside UserControl template have higher priority than explicit values inside Custom Control. If I place UserControl inside a window and override Width & Height,  it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you hard coded height/width of 100 x 100 on the UserControl - and these values have a higher precedence than when you attempted to set height/width to 5 x 5 in the CustomControl's instance of the UserControl.

Even if you define a height / width for the custom control (e.g. 5 x 5) - it wouldn't actually change the size of the user control, it would just show a 5 x 5 section of it.  This is best illustrated with an image rather than a rectangle, of course.

Comment: But why? When I place the same UserControl inside a window and override Width and Height it works as I expected. I can't understand why behavior inside custom control is different